# Does this hold anywhere close to remotely over finite fields and rings?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields, orthogonality

We know in two dimensions if $\langle u,v\rangle=1$ where $u,v\in\mathbb R^2:\|u\|=\|v\|=1$ holds and $\langle u,a\rangle=0$ holds at some $a\in\mathbb R^2$ then $\langle v,a\rangle=0$ holds.

What if instead we have $\mathbb K^2$ where $\mathbb K$ is a ring with zero divisors or $\mathbb K=\mathbb F_{p^t}$?

Answer (score 3):

Over $\mathbb{R}$ this is false, with for example $u=(1,0)$, $a=(0,1)$ and $v=(1,1)$.

Comment: I think OP's point is really about normalized $u, v$ -- the condition aims to mean "parallel vectors are orthogonal to the same vectors" -- but it's not immediately clear what this would mean in another setting.

Comment: I thought it may be this, but wasn't sure. Then, yes, I don't know if there is a natural way to define a bilinear form that would have nice properties like the scalar product has (cauchy-schwarz note having a lot of sense without an order...) so we can make sense about normalized vectors for example.

Comment: Sorry I forgot normalization.